# Scheme Cons (with #f as a second statement) output

Tags: scheme, output, cons

I was wondering, If

```
(cons (quote (a b c)) #f)
```

gives an output

```
(( a  b  c ))
```

Then what output does this give:

```
(cons (quote (a b c)) #t)
```

?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `'()` and `NIL` as both 'false' from CommonLisp.  In Scheme `'()` is not a boolean.

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't type this into a Scheme prompt and see what `(cons '(a b c) #f)` returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first expression will *not* evaluate to `((a b c))` in most interpreters, it seems that your interpreter is evaluating `#f` as an empty list:

```
(cons (quote (a b c)) '())
=> '((a b c))
```

Having said that, you just substituted a `#f` with a `#t`, the standard results will look like this:

```
(cons (quote (a b c)) #f)
=> '((a b c) . #f)

(cons (quote (a b c)) #t)
=> '((a b c) . #t)
```

Why don't you try it online? in [here](https://ideone.com/D2f35k) for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am writing a Scheme Interpreter in C, so that was one of the output samples. So if my interpreter is evaluating #f as an empty list, this means that there is nothing special with #t right?

Comment: It means two things: that there's nothing special about `#t` and `#f` when building a list, and that your interpreter is evaluating `#f` incorrectly ;) because this expression should be false: `(equal? #f '())`. Perhaps the sample output you were given is wrong?

Comment: Well, it could be wrong, but thats our assignment, so I should do it anyways :)

Comment: @epsilon If that's the case, then your assignment isn't really about Scheme, but some other language in the Lisp family.

Answer (score 0):

CommonLisp:

```
* (if '() 'true 'false)
FALSE
```

Scheme:

```
> (if '() 'true 'false)
true
```

And back in CommonLisp:

```
* (cons (quote (a b c)) nil)
((A B C))
```